# Vertical Align cell contents with first row in flex table R

Tags: r

Hello I am curious if there is a way in flextable to make the content of a multirow cell align with the top row instead of being in the center?

Here is an example you can see that the species column is multirow and the content is in the center vertically.

```r
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat <- iris


table_dat <- dat |> 
  group_by(Species) |> 
  summarise(across(everything(), mean)) |> 
  pivot_longer(-Species, 
               names_to = c("Part", ".value"),
               names_sep = "\\.")

flextable(table_dat) |> 
  merge_v()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Try `flextable(table_dat) |>  merge_v() |> valign(valign = "top")` (https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/define-visual-properties.html#format-specific-parts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `valign` to adjust the vertical alignment

```
flextable(table_dat) |> 
  merge_v() |>
  valign(valign="top", j=1)
```

See https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/valign.html for more details